# spaces in array key not working when using $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

on a website I am showing a list of car options as checkboxes.

```
<?php

foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
?>
   <dl style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <dt>
    <?= $key ?>
    </dt>
     <?php
     foreach ($value as $row ) { 
     ?>
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
          <input name="options[<?= $row ?>]" value ="1" type="checkbox"> <?= $row ?> 
         </label>
       </div>
     <?php
     }
     ?>

   </dl>

<?php
 }
 ?>
```

this gives me a checkbox like this :

```
<div class="checkbox">
 <label>
  <input name="options[2 deurs]" value ="1" type="checkbox"> 2 deurs
 </label>
</div>
```

Which is part of a form.
I get the form data from a post with like this :

```
$data["optionsarray"] = $this->input->post('options[]', TRUE);
```

I notice that when there is a space in the option name, the array key does not show that name.

so if the option name is "mirrors, the array looks like:

```
array(1) { ["mirrors"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

but if the option name is: 2 door, I get an array like this :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I have no idea why this is happening as I thought spaces were allowed in array keys?
is there any way to prevent this or should I just replace the spaces in the option names with lets say an underscore?

Comment: " i thought spaces were allowed in array keys"...sure, but not in HTTP parameter names. I suggest using some kind of ID to represent the option, rather than a human-readable description.

Comment: Not sure what framework you're using, I don't recognize `$this->input->post('options[]', TRUE)`, but in straight PHP `[2 deurs]` will become `[2_deurs]` with an underscore in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: I don't think this will necessarily solve your problem, but you should switch your use of PHP and HTML. You should just display your HTML natively instead of echoing it with PHP, and echo the variables into the correct place of your HTML. This will go lightyears in making your code more readable. Something like this https://pastebin.com/S0zdEF4W

Comment: Try just `print_r($_POST);` and see.

Comment: AbraCadaver i'm using the codeigniter framework with HMVC plugin

Comment: Should `<input name="options[2 deurs]" value ="1" type="checkbox"> 2 deurs` be `<input name="options['2 deurs']" value ="1" type="checkbox"> 2 deurs`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is how you're treating arrays in PHP. The keys can either be an integer or a string; when you leave it ambiguous, PHP attempts to decide for you. Your meaning is to use `2 deurs` as a *string* key, but PHP sees that first integer and thinks its dealing with a number. Example:

```
php > $array = [];
php > var_dump($array);
array(0) {
}
php > $array[2] = "hello";
php > var_dump($array);
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
php > $array[2 things] = "helloooo";
```

After that last command you should see something like this in php's error log:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'things' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in php shell code on line 1
```

and no new key was made:

```
php > var_dump($array);
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

Keys that have spaces are inherently strings, and if they lead with a number you definitely need to be clear to PHP that they are strings. Encapsulate the keys in quotes if they are strings.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail. The error log doesnt show any errors either. 
I get the same error when the key consists of 2 words seperated by a space. 

encapsulating doesnt work for some reason in codeigniter 3. I recreated the same scenario in plain PHP and there is does not cause any problems.